# ajax is not getting the value from form in django

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get the value from a form in Django but it's giving me this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Here is my HTML form:

```
 <form id="chat-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="chat-bottom" class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="chat-msg" name="chatmsg" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="send" type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </div>

        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

my ajax code

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit','#chat-form',functiom(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/qasim/',
        data: {
            msg:$('#chat-msg').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[msg=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()#}
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("done");}
    });

});
```

Here is my views.py:

```
class index(TemplateView):
template_name = 'qasim/chat.html'




def get(self,request):



    return render(request,self.template_name)



def post(self,request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg2 = request.POST.get('msg', None)

        return HttpResponse('')
```

I just want the value and I want to use that value in my views.py. Please help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

`csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[msg=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()#}`

with

`csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()}`